# res.status is not a function - express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a route to get user details. Here is the controller :

```
module.exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        const userDetails = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;

        sql.query(userDetails, function (err, res) {
            if (res.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).json({ res })
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: "Error with this id !" })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When i make a request to the url, I have this error :

```
TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-app/controllers/auth.controller.js:9:21)
```

Line 9 is `res.status(200).json({ res })`

Is there an error in this method ?

Thank you

Comment: `sql.query(userDetails, function (err, res) {` this `res` is hiding the express one.  Use a different name in the callback from sql.query.

Comment: @Joe thank you for your answer. Unfortunately with another name, same error with the new name 

Comment: Joe is right, just use `sql.query(userDetails, function (err, user) { if (user.length > 0)  }`

Comment: @ShivamSood i tried again, even restarted server and used ```user``` as you did, but same error ```user.name is not a function```

Comment: @Johan `user.name is not a function` that's a new error. not the one you mentioned

Comment: @Shivam sorry, I wanted to type ```user.status is not a function```. Same error with the new name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, as per your comments. You have to change the variable you are using in `sql query callback` not the one you are receiving in `getUser` function

```
module.exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        const userDetails = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;

        sql.query(userDetails, function (err, user) {
            if (user.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).json({ user })
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: "Error with this id !" })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: This change does not work. The error is still the same with the new name : ```user.status is not a function```

Comment: There is no `user.status` in the answer. So you are probably getting error at someplace else. Please check your error stack

Comment: Ooooh sorry it is my bad, i totally change all the ```res``` by ```user``` with cmd + d in VSCode, that's why all ```res``` changed. Thank you very much for your help and time